# Processing CSV files

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a CSV file which simply contains only numbers per line

example

```
12,34,56
1,2,3 
34,45,67
```

I would like to get the maximum ,minimum and average of each row.

I started coding

```
from str in File.ReadLines(@"FilePath")
.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
```

But I am not sure how to separte the values from CSV file and project the maximum,minimum,average of each row.

If you still need more information , i am happy to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code snippet

```
 var result = from str in File.ReadLines(@"FilePath")
                          let GetValue = str.Split(',')
                          .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
                          select new
                          {
                              Maximum = GetValue.Max(),
                              Minimum = GetValue.Min(),
                              Average = GetValue.Average()
                          };
```

I have simulated the result

```
 IEnumerable<string> lines = new[] { "1,2,3", "4,5,6", "45,56,67" };
       var result = from str in lines
                      let GetValue = str.Split(',')
                      .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
                      select new
                      {
                          Maximum = GetValue.Max(),
                          Minimum = GetValue.Min(),
                          Average = GetValue.Average()
                      };
```

Comment: Note you're parsing each int three times here. If perf is a concern, this could be re-written to use `Aggregate` to only parse once.

Comment: Be careful though assuming too much about the format of a CSV file. The format of a number (int or decimal) might be different and contain comma's or dots and there might be lines that are empty or contain text. CSV has more than one standard... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard

Comment: @ Erno de Weerd - :) Let him at least do some customization based on his requirement .The user did not give more information about the CSV file format he is processing.

Comment: @Cory Nelson :Well said it could be rewritten to use Aggregate